# Azure bearer authentication with OAuth or certificate?

Tags: azure, oauth, active-directory, oauth-2.0

I'm very new to Azure so I'm sorry if my terminology is a little off. I have inherited a web service which authenticates users using OAuth 2 on Azure. I have been asked to create an application which also accesses the service using using certificates like [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/).

I have implemented the above solution and it works well. However I have had to change the Audience of the service from a GUID to a URL, e.g:

```
Was: <add key="ida:Audience" value="709a****-****-****-****-*************" />
Now: <add key="ida:Audience" value="https://***.onmicrosoft.com/cafc****-****-****-****-*************" />
```

This means that users can no longer login with OAuth. Is it possible to use the same audience for both scenarios, or specify two audiences?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the same audience for both scenarios, or specify two audiences?

Yes, it is possible. The web service protected by Azure AD doesn't care about how you acquire the token. In this scenario, you want to get the token using **OAuth 2.0 code grant flow** and **Client Credential flow**. It will verify the token based on the configuration, for example like **audience**, **tenant**, etc.

Based on the description, you changed the **audience** in your web service. To make the web service to continue support the token acquired using **OAuth 2.0 code grant flow**, you need to also to change the **resource** using the new **audience**( It seems that you were acquire the token using the guid in the old request).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to split up your application into two registered applications within Azure Active Directory. You can see the authentication scenarios in the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#application-types-and-scenarios). There scenarios are:

- Web browser to web application
- Single page application
- Native application to Web API
- Web application to Web API
- Daemon or server application to Web API

Here is a diagram showing the interaction points of each authentication scenario:
[image]

As you can see each scenario has a specific method of authenticating requests to it. For your scenario you would want a web API which requests the information you need and then a browser application which your users interact with followed by a daemon which can interact with the same API.